# What exactly is the Prefix attribute on the HTML tag and why is it necessary/used?

Tags: html, rdfs

So I came across [BritishMuseum.org](https://www.britishmuseum.org/). Inspecting the HTML as you do I noticed a strange prefix attribute.

`<html lang="en" prefix="content: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/  dc: http://purl.org/dc/terms/  foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/  og: http://ogp.me/ns#  rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#  schema: http://schema.org/  sioc: http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#  sioct: http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#  skos: http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#  xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"> . . .</html>`

Doing some research: some say Open Graph, some say RDF vocabulary and some 'Foaf, (Friend of a friend)' image say XML. I'm so confused. A post on Quora said this:

> RDFa is used to implement the Semantic Web in web pages represented in many markup languages, like HTML and XML. Instead of having a web page telling the browser just how it should be structured, now you can also tell it what the page represents, like a Person, a List of Products, etc.

What do we mean by Semantic Web? We all strive to make a webpage completely accessible and 'Semantically' correct, sure. Section tags... Article tags... Can we literally enforce that by this prefix tag? This Museum site isn't a person, a List or a product but it is a place.

Why does this museum need to add this prefix tag to the HTML element?

Also inspecting... I can see what looks like Schema. Now, this does make sense because of the visibility they wish to gain through search engines.

`<img src="/src.jpg" typeof="foaf:img">`

Then on their Donate page

`<div about="/support-us/donate" typeoof="schema:WebPage"> ... </div>`

Who knew you could put URLs there? :-)

It seems with a majority of their headings we also have

`<span property="schema:name">Corporate support</span>`

Does doing this have any real benefit? And why the very long HTML prefix? Seldom seen on the web nowadays in my opinion. Penny for your thoughts on this?

Comment: Note that `prefix` is an attribute, not an element (tag).

Answer (score 1):

> What do we mean by Semantic Web?

[Wikipedia has a good introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web), but essentially it involves adding **more** machine readable data to the WWW.

> We all strive to make a webpage completely accessible and 'Semantically' correct, sure. Section tags... Article tags... Can we literally enforce that by this prefix tag?

The goal of the semantic web is to go *beyond* the semantics of HTML.

> some say Open Graph, some say RDF vocabulary and some 'Foaf, (Friend of a friend)' image say XML. I'm so confused.

[Open Graph](https://ogp.me/) is a means to encode a certain set of additional semantics.

[FOAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF) is a means to encode a *different* set of additional semantics (specifically about how people relate to each other).

[RDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) is a more generic means to encode semantics. FOAF and Open Graph are used with it.

[XML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XML/XML_introduction) is a generic markup language that is designed to be used as the foundation of other markup languages.

RDF is often expressed using XML.

---

RDFa defines the `prefix` attribute that you have quoted.

`foaf: http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/` defines a prefix for FOAF data in the document.

`og: http://ogp.me/ns#` defines a prefix for Open Graph data in the document.

Attributes then reference it. e.g. `<img src="/src.jpg" typeof="foaf:img">` states the element is what FOAF defines as `img`.

---

> Does doing this have any real benefit?

I have no data on either:

- Third party tools interacting with the data on webpages (beyond the use of social media using Open Graph for thumbnails et al)
- Any internal tools the museum is using on their own data.

> And why the very long HTML prefix?

Because they have data from a lot of namespaces.